# Auto Refresh in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing a basic app for a personal project, which includes a digital clock, an analog clock, a date display and a weather widget,
I have made the weather widget using WebView object, which loads up MSN Weather. The only thing now left is to get the WebView to refresh itself after every 15 mins.

I have read various StackOverflow posts but not able to implement any of those (I'm a newbie to app development, everything I have written in the code is by taking help from Android Development Docs or from here)

My WebView XML code :

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="352dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digitalclock"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666"></WebView>
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today/Indira-Puram,Uttar-Pradesh,India/we-city?form=PRWLAS&iso=IN&el=BrSTQuEAtMKg0ieFIZL7dsSW4wabraPd56ExjVOnG498zXJC6snI8phK%2Fm3kngtYUxMgtIHuTpASUdkcj74e18ed11%2FJGPgvtNUExJNmB6MbbUPuzf2%2B2TVwoTiWCxnz");
    webView.reload();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

    TextView textviewdate = findViewById(R.id.text_date);
    textviewdate.setText(currentDate);
}
```

}

Is there any simple way of doing the Auto-Refresh thing, without any user interaction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one method outside of onCreate  `refresh()`

```
public void refresh() {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.msn.com/en-in/weather/today/Indira-Puram,Uttar-Pradesh,India/we-city?form=PRWLAS&iso=IN&el=BrSTQuEAtMKg0ieFIZL7dsSW4wabraPd56ExjVOnG498zXJC6snI8phK%2Fm3kngtYUxMgtIHuTpASUdkcj74e18ed11%2FJGPgvtNUExJNmB6MbbUPuzf2%2B2TVwoTiWCxnz");
    //webView.reload();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

    textviewdate.setText(currentDate);
    }
}, 50000);//increase if want more time
```

call `refresh()`in oncreate method
every 5 seconds it will refreshing

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webview.loadUrl(url); // Write your url to load here 
            }
        });
       handler.postDelayed(this, timeInterval); // update your time interval here (15 min)
    }
};
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

Don't forget to remove callbacks

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);
```